# Displaying grid in aspx page not working locally

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm having a problem when displaying a grid in an aspx page.

> Image1: running the site from the testing server(works ok)
>
> Image2: Running the same site from localhost showing F12 (styles seems
>   to be ok)

Css seems to be ok, what could be the problem?
Something missing in my pc that I need to install?

Thanks

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Is the telerik installed properly in the PC which HTML messed up?

Comment: @Hatjhie no its not, I thing that may be the reason because the telerik js is not loading..
What shoud I install??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS2013? If so, **disable BrowserLink**. It breaks a lot of stuff in webforms.